# Public image upload - Risks involved / good practice

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I'm building a site (in CakePHP) which allows vistors to comment on posts and also upload an image (jpg, png, gif) along with their comment.
I want to keep the threshold as low as possible, so in order to comment visitors have to fill out a Captcha instead of registering.
Right after uploading I resample the image ( imagecopyresampled() ) and discard the original. This in order to filter malicious content.

My question regarding the image uploading:
What risks didn't I cover yet? / Did I cover the potential risks sufficiently?
+ other thoughts on this topic?

kind regards!
Bart

Comment: I would put a limit on the size of the file, like not allow the user to upload images over 5mb or something

Comment: Thanks all! I think I'll have to reconsider this idea.
Maybe provide the visitors with an embed feature for images. Though I guess I'll have to take in account some potential risks in there as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Porn
- Huge files (Filter for this)
- With that resample, many image uploads = lots of cpu time

I would suggest filtering file size and type. Honestly I stay away from user uploads as much as possible myself, they tend to cause trouble no-one expects...

Answer (score 3):

- copyright violation
- abusing your server as fileserver

So I agree with J V, the real problems are less of a technical nature.